# How can I remove a menu item programmatically?

Tags: menus

I'm using the built in menu manager to create my menues and I disaply them by using `wp_nav_menu()`.

I'm wondering, is it possible to remove certain menu items from being displayed based on some specific condition?

Comment: How about a custom menu walker? http://erikshosting.com/wordpress-tips-code/building-a-wordpress-walker-creating-custom-dynamic-menu-outputs/

Answer (score 4):

Use the wp_nav_menu_objects filter to adjust the menu items using whatever conditions you like. The filter will receive and return an array of the menu items.

Comment: I tested that earlier. But I was not able to remove the object from the array. I tested using `unset($some_name_obj)`.

Comment: You were probably unsetting it wrong. You have to unset it in the array itself to remove it from the array. Like unset($whatever['item']) then return $whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `wp_nav_menu()`, you can try using `wp_get_nav_menu_items` which will return a list of menu items, then you can have conditional statements to pick an choose which to display.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items

Comment: yeah, that might be a solution. Currently I'm using the `walker` option. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/filter-on-nav_menu_item_id-is-not-working?replies=2#post-2270242

Answer (score 0):

if our menu is pages you can use [Exclude Pages from List](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_pages#Exclude_Pages_from_List)

Just use the id of pages sepearated b comma

```
<ul>
  <?php wp_list_pages('exclude=17,38' ); ?>
</ul>
```

UPDATE

Try this one

Go to Appearance -> Menu and then from there click  "Create Menu" then add menus that you want to include and you can set a Location for menus with this code below try to explore

```
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu
```

Comment: No. I'm managing my menu items from wp-admin and must use `wp_nav_menu()`. I can't hardcode what pages are to be exluded in the menu, because it depends on some certain conditions.

Comment: try to my answer update I hope it helps

Comment: Using `wp_list_pages` without the `include` parameter, will list all pages I have. That kind of defeats the purpose of having a custom menu. The whole point is selecting specific pages to be in the menu, by using the menu admin in WP. In order to list pages added through the menu admin, one must use `wp_nav_menu` or `wp_get_nav_menu_items`.