# Show menu item only if user is logged In (not word press login)

Tags: menus, login, session

I am working on a web app word press. I am new to word press So maybe you will feel that this question is silly, I tried everything but **i don't want to use any plugin**.

here is what I need to show the register/login menu item to non-logged-in users and profile/logout menu item to logged-in-users.
But In my website I am not using word press login function wp_login() I am using web service to get the login response and then I am using sessions to control the user data and access the user data on a different page.

On profile pages I have done

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
     header("Location:http://localhost:8080/wordpress/login/");
}
else {
    //page content
}
```

I have tried this, but its not working

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {

if( isset($_SESSION['user']) ) { 
$args['menu'] = 'logged-in';
} 
return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

But how can i do this with menu items ??

Comment: Use is_user_logged_in() to check if a user is logged in.

Comment: Please [merge your accounts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 5):

Use the [wp_nav_menu_objects](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_objects/) filter to access the menu items

I have used this code:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'ad_filter_menu', 10, 2);

function ad_filter_menu($sorted_menu_objects, $args) {
    // check for the right menu to rename the menu item from
    // here we check for theme location of 'primary-menu'
    // alternatively you can check for menu name ($args->menu == 'menu_name')

    if ($args->theme_location != 'primary')  
        return $sorted_menu_objects;

    // rename the menu item that has a title of 'Log ind'
        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            foreach ($sorted_menu_objects as $key => $menu_object) {
                // can also check for $menu_object->url for example
                // see all properties to test against:
                // print_r($menu_object); die();
                if ($menu_object->title == 'Log in') {
                    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
                    $menu_object->title = $current_user->user_login . " - Log out";
                    $menu_object->url = wp_logout_url();;
                }
            }
        }
    return $sorted_menu_objects;
}
```

Found the basis for that here: [Remove a menu item in menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/86868/remove-a-menu-item-in-menu?rq=1)

Obviously you need to change the line

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
```

to

```
if( isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
```

and you may need to check for additional menu items to change their title and url depending on status (Logged in or out)